# Can a new user comment on their own post?

Tags: support, comments

During review of Late Answers, I left a comment. The user responded by posting a [new answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/25775/8273), saying that he couldn't reply to my comment until he had 50 rep.

I (perhaps mis-)understood that users could always leave comments on their own posts. Reading the [Privileges](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page only confirms my (mis)interpretation.

Can someone explain this point please?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can comment on your own posts regardless of how much reputation you have.

...But that only works if the system *knows* they're your posts.

Which it won't, if you end up using a separate account. Which the person you responded to did.

I've merged his accounts, which should alleviate the problem here.